# How to display product multiple images in Slider in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a `product` model and this product model is related to `images`, it means that a product can have multiple images, but when I am displaying product its images are not displaying. Please let me know how I can display product images in slider.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
  slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
  product=models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image=models.ImageField(upload_to='product_image',blank=False,null=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
      self.image = self.compressImage(self.image)
    super(ProductImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

  def compressImage(self, image):
    imageTemproary = Image.open(image)
    if imageTemproary.mode in ("RGBA", "P"):
      imageTemproary = imageTemproary.convert("RGBA")
    outputIoStream = BytesIO()
    imageTemproaryResized = imageTemproary.resize((1000, 700))
    imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='JPEG', quality=20)
    outputIoStream.seek(0)
    image = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField', "%s.jpg" % image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
    return image
```

Here is my `views.py` file...

```
def productview(request, slug):
  product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
  template_name='mainpage/product-view.html'
  context={'product':product}
  return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Here is my `product-view.html` file for display single product...

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="product-slick">
    <div>
      <img src="{{product.first_image.image.url}}" alt=""class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload image_zoom_cls-0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 p-0">
      <div class="slider-nav">
        <div>
        {% for img in product.image_set.all %}
        <img src="{{img.image.url}}" alt="" class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload">
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What causes the image to not be displayed? There is no image? the URL is incorrect? Please add more details about the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: I have already updated my model there, and in `product-view.html` i run a for loop for display the images of a particular product, i think mistakes are there in for loop, could you please check it.

Comment: Try `product.images.all` instead.

Comment: could you please write complete for loop.